# MongoDB Aggregation - match if value in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that I'm performing an aggregation on and I've basically gotten it down to

```
{array:[1,2,3], value: 1},
{array:[1,2,3], value: 4}
```

How would I perform an aggregation match to check if the value is in the array? I tried using `{$match: {"array: {$in: ["$value"]}}}` but it doesn't find anything.

I would want the output (if using the above as an example) to be:

```
{array:[1,2,3], value:1}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I think you probably want `$elemMatch` (see [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch)) rather than `$in` - you want to test whether a value is an the array, not whether the array is in the value!

Comment: You really need to come back and look at this question, as anyone who suggested `$unwind` gave you the worst possible performance answer you could implement in your code. There are much better alternatives submitted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A slight variation based on @chridam's answer:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$array" },
    { "$group": {
                  _id: { "_id": "$_id", "value": "$value" },
                  array: { $push: "$array" },
                  mcount: { $sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$value","$array"]},1,0]}}
                }
    },
    { $match: {mcount: {$gt: 0}}},
    { "$project": { "value": "$_id.value", "array": 1, "_id": 0 }}
])
```

The idea is to `$unwind` and `$group` back the array, counting in `mcount` the number of items matching the value. After that, a simple `$match` on `mcount > 0` will filter out unwanted documents.

Answer (score 25):

You can use aggregation expression in regular query in 3.6 version.

```
db.collection_name.find({"$expr": {"$in": ["$value", "$array"]}})
```

Using Aggregation:

You can use `$match + $expr` in current `3.6` version.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({"$match": {"$expr": {"$in": ["$value", "$array"]}}})
```

You can try `$redact + $in` expression in `3.4` version.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate({
  "$redact": {
    "$cond": [
      {
        "$in": [
          "$value",
          "$array"
        ]
      },
      "$$KEEP",
      "$$PRUNE"
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 16):

As stated, [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where) is a good option where you do not need to continue the logic in the aggregation pipeline.

But if you do then use [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/), with [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to transform the "value" into an array and use of [**`$setIsSubSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) to compare. It is the fastest way to do this since you do not need to duplicate documents using [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$redact": {
       "$cond": {
           "if": { "$setIsSubset": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": { "$literal": ["A"] },
                    "as": "a",
                    "in": "$value"
                }},
                "$array"
           ]},
           "then": "$$KEEP",
           "else": "$$PRUNE"
       }
   }}
])
```

The **`$redact`** pipeline operator allows the proccessing of a logical condition within [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and uses the special operations [**`$$KEEP`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep) to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or [**`$$PRUNE`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

This allows it to work like [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with a subsequent [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), but in a single pipeline stage which is more efficient.

Considering these are native coded operators and not JavaScript then it is likely "the" fastest way to perform your match. So provided you are using a MongoDB 2.6 version or above, then this is the way you should be doing it to compare these elements in your document.

Comment: thumbs up for $redact. I didn't know about this one and it does exactly what I need: look in each document for a specific value in an array. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

A more efficient approach would involve a single pipeline that uses the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** operator as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$setIsSubset": [ 
                        ["$value"],
                        "$array"  
                    ] 
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

---

For earlier versions of MongoDB that do not support **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** (versions < 2.6) then consider this aggregation pipeline that uses the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$array" },
    {
        "$project": {
            "isInArray": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$array", "$value" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "value": 1,
            "array": 1
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "isInArray": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "value": "$value"
            },
            "array": { "$push": "$array" },
            "isInArray": { "$first": "$isInArray" }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "isInArray": 1 } },
    { "$project": { "value": "$_id.value", "array": 1, "_id": 0 } }
])
```

Answer (score 5):

A little late to answer but this presents another solution:

By using addFields and match separately, this gives more flexibility than the redact.  You can expose several fields and then use other matching logic together based on the results.

```
db.applications.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {"containsValueInArray": {$cond:[{$setIsSubset: [["valueToMatch"], "$arrayToMatchIn"]},true,false]}}},
    {$match: {"containsValueInArray":true}}
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the combination of $eq and $setIntersection

```
{$group :{
  _id: "$id",
  yourName :  { $sum:
  { $cond :[
       {$and : [
          {$eq:[{$setIntersection : ["$someArrayField", ["$value"]]  },["$value"]]}
         ]
      },1,0]
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

i prefer without grouping, there's an easy approach since v.3.2

```
...aggregate([
      {
        $addFields: {
          arrayFilter: {
            $filter: {
              input: '$array',
              as: 'item',
              cond: ['$$item', '$value']
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$arrayFilter'
      },
      {
        $project: {
          arrayFilter: 0
        }
      }
    ]);
```

1. Add a temporary filter field
2. $unwind on the resulting array (pipeline results with empty arrays get removed)
3. (optional) remove filter field from result via project

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with simple $project & $match

```
db.test.aggregate([{
$project: {
              arrayValue: 1,
              value: 1,
              "has_same_value" : { $in: ["$value", "$arrayValue"] }
          }
},
{
   $match: {has_same_value: true}
},
{
  $project: {has_same_value: 0}
}])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      "$match": { "name": { "$in":["Rio","Raja"] }} }])
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25565726)

Comment: Here's the basic examples of $Match and $in using array of name in String